# How to get html of EPUB by page in flutter?

Tags: flutter, epub, flutter-packages, flutter-html

I want to get the HTML content of an epub file by page. I tried epubx package but it's not working correctly. Has anyone managed to get HTML of an epub by page?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/epub_view try this

Comment: What I need is not to show the epub directly. I need to get the HTML of epub

Answer (score 0):

Try this package [epub_parser](https://pub.dev/packages/epub_parser)

You can fetch html like the following

```
// Enumerating chapters
epubBook.Chapters.forEach((EpubChapter chapter) {
          
  // HTML content of current chapter
  String chapterHtmlContent = chapter.HtmlContent;

});
```

Comment: I've tried epub_parser and also epubx but those are probably the same package and unfortunately it has tons of bugs like not converting all pages.

Comment: That is partially dependant on the epub file also. Some are images converted to a page which cannot be converted to html if it has text. To test this package convert a normal word document to epub and try using that epub file. It should be able to convert to html completely.